# Unity will not log on

Tags: unity, 14.04, lightdm

Unity will only log onto the guest version on my computer, when I type in my password normally it momentarily flashes to a black screen then return to the login screen.

When running unity through terminal, I find:

`Stop: unknown job unity-panel-service`

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 and this bug seemed to arise after I attempted to install the mate desktop.

Comment: dupe? http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration